# Line breaks after brackets

Tags: brackets

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Field}[1]{
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}%

    {%
        \fontsize{12.0pt}{14.4pt} \selectfont%
        \noindent%
        \rule{1.0in}{1.0pt}%

        \noindent%
        #1%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\field}[1]{
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}%

    {%
        \fontsize{12.0pt}{14.4pt} \selectfont%
        \noindent%
        \rule{1.0in}{1.0pt}%

        \noindent%
        #1%

    }%
}

\begin{document}

    \Field{By}

    \hfill

    \field{By}

\end{document}
```

Observe that the only difference between `\Field` and `\field` is that `\field` has an extra line break in its definition. Now, upon compilation, there is a noticeable extra vertical space between the rule and the text for `\field` but not for `\Field`. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: both definitions have blank lines in them.  in a case like this (especially where you've been extra careful to insert `%` signs at the ends of lines to avoid spurious spaces), it's generally better to use an explicit `\par`, or even `\endgraf`, to indicate a shift into vertical mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usual issue that any font change command should include the final paragraph end in its scope, otherwise the paragraph will be set with the *original* baselineskip.

In `\Field` the font size is changed but the paragraph is set to a normalize baselineskip as the scope of the size change ends before the end of the paragraph.

Note that you have `%` at the end of several lines where they are not needed (`\noindent%` but the definition has several spurious space characters at other places, I marked with `%%` here.

```
\newcommand{\field}[1]{%%
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}%

    {%
        \fontsize{12.0pt}{14.4pt}%%
        \selectfont
        \noindent
        \rule{1.0in}{1.0pt}%

        \noindent
        #1%

    }%
}
```

As Barbara said, it's clearer to use `\par` in macro definitions.